# How do I install a .reg file with Python

Tags: python-3.x, regedit

How do I use Python to install a .reg file?

I tried to search it up but found no answer of how to install a .reg file
with Python.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how to install .reg using python?Then use this code in python shell

```
from winregistry import WinRegistry as Reg
    reg = Reg()
    path = r'HKLM\SOFTWARE\remove_me'
    reg.create_key(path + r'\test')
    True if 'remove_me' in reg.read_key(r'HKLM\SOFTWARE')['keys'] else False
    reg.write_value(path, 'Value name', b'21', 'REG_BINARY')
    reg.read_key(path)
    {'keys': ['test'], 'values': [{'value': 'Value name', 'data': b'21...
    reg.read_value(path, 'Value name')
    {'value': 'Value name', 'data': b'21', 'type': 'REG_BINARY'}
    reg.delete_value(path, 'Value name')
    reg.delete_key(path + r'\test')
    reg.read_key(path)
    {'keys': [], 'values': [], 'modify': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 16...
    reg.delete_key(path)
    True if 'remove_me' in reg.read_key(r'HKLM\SOFTWARE')['keys'] else False
```